# "Invalid Object Name" when deploying database project with COLLATE in cross-database join

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

I'm attempting to deploy a database project, *Operations*, that builds without errors.  The deployment is failing with an "Invalid object name" error.  The object name in the error is a three-part name, of an object in another database project, *Company*.  The name is valid: The object exists in *Company*, there is a database reference in the *Operations* project to the *Company* project, and the three-part name appears in other objects in the *Operations* project without causing an error.

As far as I can see, the reason for the error is that the three-part name appears in a join which uses a COLLATE statement.  eg

```
CREATE VIEW BranchDetails 
AS
SELECT b.BranchID, bu.LocationID
FROM Branch b
INNER JOIN Company.dbo.BusinessUnit bu on b.BranchAbbreviation = bu.[Name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

The COLLATE statement is needed because the two databases have different collations and it's not possible to join on columns with different collations without converting the collation of one column or the other.

Is there some workaround that will allow me to deploy the database without the "Invalid object name" error?

---

**EDIT:** Looks like the COLLATE statement may have been a red herring.  I replaced the view with a dummy one:

```
CREATE VIEW BranchDetails 
AS
SELECT NULL AS BranchID, NULL AS LocationID;
```

Then dealt with other errors until I was able to deploy the database.  I then copied the original text of the BranchDetails CREATE VIEW back into the script and the database built and deployed without error.

The only explanations I can think of are:

1) In copying the view text out and then back in again later, I somehow omitted something that was causing the error;

2) The error was actually related to one of the other errors I fixed when I replaced the view with the dummy text, and Visual Studio was giving me an incorrect error message pointing to the wrong .sql file.  I suppose this is possible as the other errors were related to the server name included in four-part names in a stored procedure not existing in our dev environment.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the COLLATE statement to verify that it will build correctly without it? Workaround would be to make this a post-deploy script, but that gets ugly.

Comment: @PeterSchott: Tried commenting it out.  Builds okay (but it built okay to start with) but still fails deployment.  Now the error is "Cannot resolve the collation conflict in the equal to operation."